# 2-d Arrays in C

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

So, this program is supposed to take stats from Auburn's football season and compute averages for each game and the whole season and print them on the screen in a chart. I thought I had figured this out, but I keep getting errors while trying to compile. I'm sure I'm missing some other stuff too, but I should figure that out once I get the program to compile and give me results. I would probably know what was going on if my teacher decided to teach the class. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here are some of the errors I'm getting:

> error: expected ')' before '[' token  - this shows up on all of my compAvg functions.
>
> error: expected expression before ']' token  -  this one shows up at the numGames=getStats line.
>
> error: too few arguments to function 'analysis'
>
> error: 'numGames' undeclared here (not in a function)  - this appears at the void analysis function and I'm guessing it has to do with the last error.
>
> error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer  - this is coming up on my first second printf line

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <math.h>

#define MAXGAMES 15
#define AUSTATS "auPass2010.txt"


int main() //main function
{
double date[MAXGAMES][2], oppName[MAXGAMES], inStats[MAXGAMES][4], outStats[MAXGAMES][3];       //declare variables
double avgCmp, avgAtt, avgYds, avgTD, avgPts;                                                                
int numGames=0, n=0,r,c;


int getStats(int date[][2], char oppName[], double inStats[][4]);//prototypes
void analysis( double inStats[][4], double outStats[][3], double numGames);
double compAvgCmp(stat[][], numGames);
double compAvgAtt(stat[][], numGames);
double compAvgYds(stat[][], numGames);
double compAvgTD(stat[][], numGames);
double compAvgPts(stat[][], numGames);

numGames = getStats(date[][2], oppName[], inStats[][4]);

printf("\t\t2010 AUBURN PASSING STATISTICS\nDATE\tOPPONENT\t\tCMP\tATT\tYDS\tTD --\tAVEYDS\t%CMP\tPTS\n-----\t-------------\t----\t----\t----\t"); //prints header  

if(numGames <= 0) printf("%s NO GAMES READ\n", AUSTATS);

else
{
    analysis(double inStats[][4], double outStats[][3], double numGames);

    printf("d\n", numGames);

    for ( r=0;r<numGames;r++ )
    {
        for(c=0;c<=4;c++)
        {
            printf("%2d/%2d\t%s\t\t%5.0d\t%5.0d\t%5.0d\t%5.0d\t   \t%6.1lf\t%6.1lf\t%5.0lf\n", date[r][0], date[r][1], oppName[r][0], inStats[r][0], inStats[r][1], inStats[r][2], inStats[r][3], outStats[r][0], outStats[r][1], outStats[r][2]);
        }
    }           
}

avgCmp = compAvgCmp(inStats[numGames][4], numGames);
avgAtt = compAvgCmp(inStats[numGames][4], numGames);
avgYds = compAvgCmp(inStats[numGames][4], numGames);
avgTD = compAvgCmp(inStats[numGames][4], numGames);
avgPts = compAvgCmp(outStats[numGames][4], numGames);

printf("-----\t------------------\t----\t----\t-----\t---\t\t\t----\n");
printf("Season Averages\t\t\t%3.1f\t%3.1f\t%3.1f\t%3.1f\t\t\t3.1f\n", avgCmp, avgAtt, avgYds, avgTD, avgPts);

return 0;
}


int getStats(int date[][2], char oppName[], double inStats[][4])
{
FILE *infile;
int n=0;

infile = fopen(AUSTATS, "r");

if(infile == NULL) printf("%s FILE OPEN ERROR\n");
while(fscanf(infile, "%d %d %s %lf %lf %lf %lf", 
                date[n][0], date[n][1], oppName[n], inStats[n][0], inStats[n][1], inStats[n][2], inStats[n][3]) !=EOF) n++;

return n;
}

void analysis(double inStats[numGames][4], double outStats[numGames][3], double numGames)
{
int n;

for ( n=0;n<numGames;n++)
{
    outStats[n][0] = inStats[n][2] / inStats[n][0];
    outStats[n][1] = inStats[n][0] / inStats[n][1] * 100;
    outStats[n][2] = inStats[n][3] * 6;
}
}

double compAvgCmp(stat[][], numGames)
{
int n; 
double sum=0;

for (n=0;n<=numGames;n++)
{
    sum += stat[n][0]
}

return sum / numGames;
}

double compAvgAtt(stat[][], numGames)
{
int n; 
double sum=0;

for (n=0;n<=numGames;n++)
{
    sum += stat[n][1]
}

return sum / numGames;
}       

double compAvgYds(stat[][], numGames)
{
int n; 
double sum=0;

for (n=0;n<=numGames;n++)
{
    sum += stat[n][2]
}

return sum / numGames;
}

double compAvgTD(stat[][], numGames)
{
int n; 
double sum=0;

for (n=0;n<=numGames;n++)
{
    sum += stat[n][3]
}

return sum / numGames;
}

double compAvgPts(stat[][], numGames)
{
int n; 
double sum=0;

for (n=0;n<=numGames;n++)
{
    sum += stat[n][2]
}

return sum / numGames;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you're passing the arrays, you just cite the names at the calling site:

```
numGames = getStats(date[][2], oppName[], inStats[][4]);
```

```
numGames = getStats(date, oppName, inStats);
```

It is in the called functions that you use (more or less) the notation you showed.

However, when your function accepts a multi-dimensional array, you **must** specify the sizes of the second and subsequent dimensions in the function's argument list.

```
double compAvgTD(stat[][], numGames)
```

```
double compAvgTD(double stat[][4], int numGames)
```

This applies both in the declarations inside `main()` and in the definitions of the functions.  Note that I added the types, too.

---

As another answerer pointed out, it is aconventional (though not actually wrong) to declare the functions inside `main()`.  If the declared functions would be called from any other function, then it would be bad to declare the functions inside `main()` - you'd have to repeat yourself to declare the functions in the other functions from which they are called, in contradiction of the Agile dictum: **DRY** Don't Repeat Yourself.

---

#### The "I'm A Gullible Mug" Compiling Solution

There were many changes necessary to get the code to compile.  The code has not been run.

There is at least one bug left in here - the `compAvgPts()` function uses the same statistic as `cmpAvgYds()` which is likely to give inflated statistics on the points.  Fixing that requires moderately major surgery; I think you're missing two columns of data in the input (the score for each team).

However, the code does compile cleanly on MacOS X 10.6.5 using GCC 4.2.1 with the command line:

```
gcc -O -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes \
     -Wold-style-definition   xx.c -o xx
```

Note that I had to move the function declarations out of `main()`; otherwise, the compiler warned that there was no prototype in scope.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <math.h>

#define MAXGAMES 15
#define AUSTATS "auPass2010.txt"

int getStats(int date[][2], char oppName[][64], double inStats[][4]);
void analysis(double inStats[][4], double outStats[][3], int numGames);
double compAvgCmp(double stat[][4], int numGames);
double compAvgAtt(double stat[][4], int numGames);
double compAvgYds(double stat[][4], int numGames);
double compAvgTD(double stat[][4], int numGames);
double compAvgPts(double stat[][4], int numGames);

int main(void)
{
    int date[MAXGAMES][2];
    char oppName[MAXGAMES][64];
    double inStats[MAXGAMES][4];
    double outStats[MAXGAMES][3];
    double avgCmp, avgAtt, avgYds, avgTD, avgPts;
    int numGames=0, r,c;

    numGames = getStats(date, oppName, inStats);

    printf("\t\t2010 AUBURN PASSING STATISTICS\n"
            "DATE\tOPPONENT\t\tCMP\tATT\tYDS\tTD --\tAVEYDS\t%%CMP\tPTS\n"
            "-----\t-------------\t----\t----\t----\n");

    if (numGames <= 0)
        printf("%s NO GAMES READ\n", AUSTATS);
    else
    {
        analysis(inStats, outStats, numGames);
        printf("%d\n", numGames);

        for (r=0;r<numGames;r++)
        {
            for (c=0;c<=4;c++)
            {
                printf("%2d/%2d\t%s\t\t%5.0f\t%5.0f\t%5.0f\t%5.0f\t   \t%6.1lf\t%6.1lf\t%5.0lf\n",
                        date[r][0], date[r][1], &oppName[r][0], inStats[r][0], inStats[r][1],
                        inStats[r][2], inStats[r][3], outStats[r][0], outStats[r][1], outStats[r][2]);
            }
        }           

        avgCmp = compAvgCmp(inStats, numGames);
        avgAtt = compAvgAtt(inStats, numGames);
        avgYds = compAvgYds(inStats, numGames);
        avgTD  = compAvgTD(inStats, numGames);
        avgPts = compAvgPts(inStats, numGames);

        printf("-----\t------------------\t----\t----\t-----\t---\t\t\t----\n");
        printf("Season Averages\t\t\t%3.1f\t%3.1f\t%3.1f\t%3.1f\t\t\t%3.1f\n", avgCmp, avgAtt, avgYds, avgTD, avgPts);
    }

    return 0;
}

int getStats(int date[][2], char oppName[][64], double inStats[][4])
{
    FILE *infile;
    int n=0;

    infile = fopen(AUSTATS, "r");

    if (infile == NULL)
        printf("%s FILE OPEN ERROR\n", AUSTATS);
    else
    {
        while (fscanf(infile, "%d %d %63s %lf %lf %lf %lf", 
                    &date[n][0], &date[n][1], oppName[n], &inStats[n][0], &inStats[n][1],
                    &inStats[n][2], &inStats[n][3]) == 7)
            n++;
        fclose(infile);
    }

    return n;
}

void analysis(double inStats[][4], double outStats[][3], int numGames)
{
    int n;

    for (n=0;n<numGames;n++)
    {
        outStats[n][0] = inStats[n][2] / inStats[n][0];
        outStats[n][1] = inStats[n][0] / inStats[n][1] * 100;
        outStats[n][2] = inStats[n][3] * 6;
    }
}

double compAvgCmp(double stat[][4], int numGames)
{
    int n; 
    double sum=0;

    for (n=0;n<=numGames;n++)
    {
        sum += stat[n][0];
    }

    return sum / numGames;
}

double compAvgAtt(double stat[][4], int numGames)
{
    int n; 
    double sum=0;

    for (n=0;n<=numGames;n++)
    {
        sum += stat[n][1];
    }

    return sum / numGames;
}       

double compAvgYds(double stat[][4], int numGames)
{
    int n; 
    double sum=0;

    for (n=0;n<=numGames;n++)
    {
        sum += stat[n][2];
    }

    return sum / numGames;
}

double compAvgTD(double stat[][4], int numGames)
{
    int n; 
    double sum=0;

    for (n=0;n<=numGames;n++)
    {
        sum += stat[n][3];
    }

    return sum / numGames;
}

double compAvgPts(double stat[][4], int numGames)
{
    int n; 
    double sum=0;

    for (n=0;n<=numGames;n++)
    {
        sum += stat[n][2];
    }

    return sum / numGames;
}
```

Comment: I'm still getting errors trying to pass the arrays:  warning: passing argument 2 of 'getStats' from incompatible pointer type

Comment: this is what I modified it to: numGames = getStats(date, oppName, inStats);

Answer (score 0):

A quick glance answer: Why do you want to declare the functions inside the main function? Declare them above the main function.

Also, I think all your function calls are incorrect. Most of your functions expect arrays, but the way you are passing them are incorrect.

For Ex:

when you call the function

```
int getStats(int date[][2], char oppName[], double inStats[][4]);
```

You must do it like:

```
getStats(date, oppName, inStats)
```

EDIT: As correctly mentioned by Jonathan Leffer, for multi-dimensional arrays, second and subsequent dimensions must be passed.

Check the below links. These might help:

http://bytes.com/topic/c/insights/772412-arrays-revealed

http://cboard.cprogramming.com/c-programming/97898-passing-2-dimensional-array-function.html

Comment: Our teacher recommended we do it for some reason, but I guess it doesn't really matter.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/940402/function-prototype-declared-inside-main-best-practice - Check this for declaring functions within main!

Comment: Isn't the numGames argument the number of actual games - or the size of the array?

Comment: @Jonathan, Sorry. My Mistake. Corrected & Thanks for pointing it out. : )