# identifier function location question in C

Tags: c, function, identity

I tried to the identifier function try_to_change_it() with two styles as below, it produced the same result. Which style is recommend?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>

// style1 declare try_to_change_it() here
void try_to_change_it(int);

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int a = 1;

    // style2 declare try_to_change_it() here
    void try_to_change_it(int);

    printf("%d\n", a);
    try_to_change_it(a);
    printf("%d\n", a);

    return 0;
}

void try_to_change_it(int a)
{
    a = 777;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Function prototype declared inside main - best practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/940402/function-prototype-declared-inside-main-best-practice)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It makes no real difference. In a typical case, you declare functions by including a header, which you normally want to do outside any function.