# Is it bad practice to have a function prototype in the main in C

Tags: c

For example

```
int main () {
    void funct (...);

    return 0;
}

void funct (...) {

}
```

Is this bad practice in C ? because it compiles fine. Thanks. Sorry for the indentation im using my phone

Comment: Why do you need to...

Comment: Voting to close as dupe. The duplicate has better answers IMO.

Answer (score 2):

I would have done it like this:

```
// forward declaration of the function
void some_function();

int main () 
{
    // call the function
    some_function();

    .....

    return 0; 
}

// define the function
void some_function()
{
    .....
}
```

Comment: Thanks. However, is the other way looked down upon or is it fine?

Comment: If it compiles then it is fine, as the compiler is always the final judge. But as I said I would not have done it that way, only because as you start adding in more functions and as you add in the local variable, now everything will end up in that space.

Comment: Fair enough, your right. I was just asking because I had a particular case. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I would say it is bad, yes. It just makes things more convoluted and harder to follow with no real benefit. Put the prototype at the top level above the function invocations/definition, or in a header file if you want it to be public.

Answer (score 1):

The disadvantage of having the function prototype inside `main()` (or any other function) is that you have to redeclare it in any other function that uses it, which means you lose the single point of checking.

You *should* have a prototype declaration in scope before you use a function.

You *should* have only one prototype declaration for a function.  (And, since it apparently isn't obvious why you should only have one prototype for a function, or one occurrence of any declaration of any sort, the reason is that in 'real-world code' you can't afford the multiple-maintenance problems that you run into if there's more than one declaration.  If there are repetitions and you need to change something, you have far more work to do if there's more than one declaration.  This is known as the **DRY** principle — Don't Repeat Yourself; it is also known as the **SPOT** principle — Single Point of Truth.  Maintainable code avoids repetition!)

- If the function is static, you can either define the function before it is used, or declare it at the top of the file.
- If the function is externally visible, it means it is intended to be used outside the file it is defined in.  There should be one header that declares the function, and that header should be used in both the source file where it is defined and in all the source files where it is used.
- You can have GCC enforce these rules with `-Wmissing-prototypes`; I use `-Wstrict-prototypes` and `-Wold-style-definition` and `-Wold-style-definition` too (not all versions of GCC support all of these).

So, yes, it is bad to have a declaration of a function inside `main()`.

Comment: This answer is somewhat incomplete since it's not clear why you should only have one prototype, but that's covered somewhat better in an answer to the duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/a/940507/1339987